# How to move the UITextview at text enter on inside keyboard in iPhone

Tags: iphone, keyboard, ios6, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` in subview of `UIView`.I will change the texview height based on the text in the method **textViewDidChange** . My thought is when the text view height under goes to inside the keyboard i cant visible the entering text in the textview. How can solve the issue `textview` text range over to the keyboard. How to make the entered text to appear for user.

Comment: follow this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: why are you changing textView height , just fix textView height..

Comment: Do you need solution or not????/

Answer (score 1):

You can check the size of your text with the font like this:

```
[@"MYString" sizeWithFont:myFont];
```

Knowing this, you can compare it with the size of the textview and now when your text is bigger!

Comment: I want to move the textview enter inside the keyboard texview move to up of the keyboard based on the text

Answer (score 0):

Move the textview up when it reaches the keyboard, or lower the font size when the text exceeds the maximum textview size.

Comment: If you are going to pay for my time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take this `UITextView` in `UIScrollView` and then set content size with the contentSize of `UITextView` and scroll the `UIScrollView` at bottom

set content size like bellow..

```
float sizescrollview = yourTextView.frame.origin.y + yourTextView.frame.size.height + 20;
scrview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, sizescrollview);
```

and scroll the `UIScrollView` above of the keyboard like bellow..

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
scrView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -150, 320, scrView.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

i hope this help you...